# Fiddler update, gives exception "Field+not+found+Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.scriptRules"

Tags: fiddler

I just automatically updated my Fiddler to v4.6.20171.7553 and now I'm getting exceptions when I start fiddler:

> Unhandled exception... 
>   Field not found: 'Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.scriptRules'

I realized that it was failing to load my `FiddlerScript` tab.  I renamed the file `RulesTab2.dll` so I can start fiddler without the error now, but I can no longer conveniently customize my rules.  Is there a fix for this?

Here are the details from the exception:

> See the end of this message for details on invoking  just-in-time
>   (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ************** Exception Text ************** System.MissingFieldException: Field not found:
>   'Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.scriptRules'.    at
>   RulesTab2.RulesTab2.EnsureReady()    at
>   RulesTab2.RulesTab2.tabsViews_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)    at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.WmSelChange()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
>   IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>
> ************** Loaded Assemblies ************** mscorlib
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Fiddler
>       Assembly Version: 4.6.20171.7553
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.20171.7553
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Fiddler2/Fiddler.exe
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Core
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Drawing
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Telerik.Analytics
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.104.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.104
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Fiddler2/Telerik.Analytics.DLL
>   ---------------------------------------- Xceed.Zip.v5.4
>       Assembly Version: 5.4.13572.13590
>       Win32 Version: 5.4.13572.13590
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Fiddler2/Xceed.Zip.v5.4.DLL
>   ---------------------------------------- Xceed.Compression.Formats.v5.4
>       Assembly Version: 5.4.13572.13590
>       Win32 Version: 5.4.13572.13590
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Fiddler2/Xceed.Compression.Formats.v5.4.DLL
>   ---------------------------------------- Xceed.FileSystem.v5.4
>       Assembly Version: 5.4.13572.13590
>       Win32 Version: 5.4.13572.13590
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Fiddler2/Xceed.FileSystem.v5.4.DLL
>   ---------------------------------------- Xceed.Compression.v5.4
>       Assembly Version: 5.4.13572.13590
>       Win32 Version: 5.4.13572.13590
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Fiddler2/Xceed.Compression.v5.4.DLL
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Configuration
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Xml
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Standard
>       Assembly Version: 2.6.2.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.6.2.0
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Fiddler2/Inspectors/Standard.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- SyntaxView
>       Assembly Version: 2.6.2.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.6.2.0
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Fiddler2/Inspectors/SyntaxView.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- FInstStudio
>       Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
>       CodeBase: file:///D:/Documents/Fiddler2/Scripts/FInstStudio.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- HtmlAgilityPack
>       Assembly Version: 1.4.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 1.4.0.0
>       CodeBase: file:///D:/Documents/Fiddler2/Scripts/HtmlAgilityPack.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Geoedge
>       Assembly Version: 1.2.5.0
>       Win32 Version: 1.2.5.0
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Fiddler2/Scripts/Geoedge.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- RulesTab2
>       Assembly Version: 2.6.2.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.6.2.0
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Fiddler2/Scripts/RulesTab2.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- SimpleFilter
>       Assembly Version: 2.6.2.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.6.2.0
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Fiddler2/Scripts/SimpleFilter.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Timeline
>       Assembly Version: 2.6.0.3
>       Win32 Version: 2.6.0.3
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Fiddler2/Scripts/Timeline.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.JScript
>       Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 14.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.JScript/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.JScript.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Windows
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Windows.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- JScript Thunk Assembly
>       Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 14.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.JScript/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.JScript.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- YHuHIz5c
>       Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 14.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.JScript/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.JScript.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.mshtml
>       Assembly Version: 7.0.3300.0
>       Win32 Version: 7.0.3300.0
>
> ### CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/assembly/GAC/Microsoft.mshtml/7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.mshtml.dll
>
> ************** JIT Debugging ************** To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this application or computer
>   (machine.config) must have the jitDebugging value set in the
>   system.windows.forms section. The application must also be compiled
>   with debugging enabled.
>
> For example:
>
> When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception will be sent to
>   the JIT debugger registered on the computer rather than be handled by
>   this dialog box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: I tried installing Fiddler fresh and now it works fine.  Apparently the install didn't work right the first time, perhaps because I accidentally started it twice?